# How to protect form data on my site?

Tags: php, security, post

I have this page which posts data to another url. I tried using cURL but didn't work since I need the user to be redirected to the destination website and cURL was just bringing it into the current one. 
So what I'm doing is

```
<form action='http://destination.com' method='post' name='frm'>
 <input type='hidden' name='account_id' value='<?php echo $_SESSION["accont_id"]; ?>'>
</form>
<script>
 document.frm.submit();
</script>
```

But obviously this is totally insecure, and any user using a program like charles proxy can intercept and change this data. Is there a way to protect it? Validation won't do the job because the users are aware of the kind of data my database have, they know everyone's account id and I can't change that. What can I do? Maybe encryption will work?
Even if the user is able to change the data it's ok as long as they can't change it to other valid account's id. I'm thinking in something like secret/hash but can't put all together in my mind.

I tried using this:

```
$url = 'http://www.destination.com'; 
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'account_id='.$_SESSION["account_id"]);  
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl); 
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://destination.com'/>";
```

But the page was redirected and no data arrived. The post wouldn't go through

Comment: First: transport level security is done by using `https`. Second: your question is very vague here, but it sounds like you want to post some data to some other system and then redirect your use to that system?That certainly is possible by combining `cURL` and a redirection header.

Comment: Sending the `$_SESSION` value is counterproductive for security. Just use `start_session()` on the page you direct to and you should be able to grab the `account_id` from the session.

Comment: @arkascha I tried that but the value didn't go through.

Comment: @RST can't get it to work like You said, when I call session start nothing happens. And the values are not set

Comment: Sorry, but just claiming "does not work" without anything else will not help.

Comment: @arkascha I said everything that had to be said. the value didn't get to the page. The post was not there

Comment: OK, then things are broken. Pretty bad situation.

Comment: @RST If the form is being sent to another site then any use of SESSION is obviously useless

Comment: @arkascha Can you show a sample of cURL with a redirection? Just like a form does, please. Maybe I was trying the wrong way

Comment: Not until you answer my question in my first comment, since I am not sure what you are actually trying to do, sorry.

Comment: SHow use your attempt at cURL, that is the most likely method to achieve your requirement of keeping some values secret from the page user

Comment: @arkascha yes, that's what I'm trying to do, post some data to some other system and then redirect the user to that system

Comment: And your statement is that you failed to post a value to another system by means of `cURL`, right? I suggest you post your attempt so far, we will help you fix it. Because that is exactly what `cURL` is for. About the redirection: if yuo _first_ want to post the value and _then_ redirect the user, then those are two steps. First is done by curl and second by means of a header. But note that this results in _two_ separate requests to that remote system. One from your server, once from the client. There is no connection on the remote side like that.

Comment: @arkascha I edited the question and added the attempt by cURL. On the destination side I'm getting this account id post and setting up the session with its value, but when I redirect to there the session is not set

Comment: Sure, that cannot work, but this has nothing to do with `cURL`. As said: the `cURL` request comes from the server, the request following the header redirection comes from the client. Those two requests have nothing in common from the point of view of the remote system. You have to offer some "glue" so that the client is accepted. Typically that is done by some "one time token" prepared inthe `cURL` requests reply and used to access the remote system by the client. The difference is that such tokens cannot be guessed by people manipulating the communication.

Comment: Does implementing such system take too much work? Is it hard?

Comment: @RiggsFolly that is right, I didn't get that right away.

Comment: @arkascha any direction for me to start?

Comment: Not much more to be said, sorry. You make the `cURL` request to the remote system posting the `user id`, so server to server. The remote system creates some random token (random 32 char string) and returns that, it stores that token together with the posted `user id` for later reference. Now the local system sends a redirection header to the client which includes that token. That leads to the client making a request to the remote system claiming the token it was handed. The remote system checks for a stored token, can derive the `user id` from it, create a user session and delete the token.

Comment: Wow, that is some good information there xD. I was confused before but now you gave me the whole idea on how to do it. Seems pretty simple, I hope it is indeed. Trying that now, thank You very much sir

Comment: @arkascha You made my day, in a few minutes I managed to get it working. thank You very much. Make this an answer so I can accept it please.

Comment: Glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line of the discussion in the comments above results in this approach to what you actually try to do:

You make the cURL request to the remote system posting the user id, so server to server. The remote system creates some random token (random 32 char string) and returns that, it stores that token together with the posted user id for later reference. Now the local system sends a redirection header to the client which includes that token. That leads to the client making a request to the remote system claiming the token it was handed. The remote system checks for a stored token, can derive the user id from it, create a user session and delete the token.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank You! I'm just wondering why many times I go to the token table and there's dozens of them over there, it's like someone is trying to log in but closes the browser before the token is deleted or something. But anyway, this works pretty good. Thank You very much sir

Comment: Hm, you may want to investigate that by correlating time stamps of requests with the creation date of those tokens... Also if you (as you hopefully do) deliver your pages with the encrypted https protocol, you should really make sure the forwarding works like that, from domain to domain. This could be an issue if your pages are somehow using iframes. Last not least you will have to implement some sort of cleanup job that removes unused tokens from that table in a periodic manner. Something like a cron job starting once every 10 minutes removing all tokens older than 5 minutes.

Comment: I do not use https. That's what I thought, Imma create a cronn job to clean the old tokens

Comment: You do not use encryption, although you require users to login?  Why not?

Comment: To use https don't I have to buy certificate?

Comment: You had to, indeed, though that actually is less expensive than expected. However things have changed: take a look at the "Let's encrypt" project: https://letsencrypt.org/  Unlike all prior projects into that direction this one has the advantage to be accepted and backed by the important browser companies. That means that their free certificates will be accepted as valid out of the box, which is what you need when operating a website. Integration is different than with classical certificates, but actually even much easier, nor more difficult. I switched to those and it works for me.